# Multiple "COUNT" checks prior to Data Insert

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, count

Having a total blonde moment here so apologies in advance...!

I want to carry out two COUNT conditions prior to entering a new customer recorded into a DB. The below code checks to see if the Username is already in use and rejects the registration if this is applicable. I would like to add an additional COUNT to check if the "CustomerEmail", taken from txtEmail already exists in the DB as well.

Comment: First thing to do, before any logic changes, is to parametrise *all* your queries to reduce the possibility of SQL Injection.

Comment: you can have a single stored proc which can give you both the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a stored procedure to do this something like....

And obviously use appropriate data types for the params

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertUser
  @FirstName     VARCHAR(100) 
, @Surname       VARCHAR(100) 
, @Email         VARCHAR(100) 
, @Address       VARCHAR(100) 
, @Town          VARCHAR(100) 
, @City          VARCHAR(100) 
, @Postcode      VARCHAR(100) 
, @ContactNumber VARCHAR(100) 
, @Username      VARCHAR(100) 
, @Password      VARCHAR(100)
, @UserAdded     INT           OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM  [Customer] WITH (UPDLOCK)
               WHERE CustomerUserName = @Username)
    BEGIN 
       INSERT INTO [Customer] (CustomerFirstName,CustomerSurname,CustomerEmailAddress,CustomerAddress,CustomerAddressTown,CustomerAddressCity,CustomerAddressPostcode,CustomerContactNumber,CustomerUserName,CustomerPassword) 
       VALUES (@FirstName, @Surname,@Email, @Address, @Town, @City, @Postcode,@ContactNumber,@Username,@Password)

        SET @UserAdded = 1;
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN

       SET @UserAdded = 0;
    END

END
```

Application code would look something like.....

```
// define connection and command, in using blocks to ensure disposal
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(pvConnectionString ))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_InsertUser", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // set up the parameters
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserAdded", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Surname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    // and so on.....


    // set parameter values
    cmd.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = txtFirstName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@Surname"].Value = txtSurname.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@Email"].Value = txtEmail.Text;
    // and so on.....

    // open connection and execute stored procedure
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // read output value from @NewId
    int UserAdded = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@UserAdded"].Value);

    if (UserAdded == 1)
    {

        Response.Write("User already exists.");
    }

    conn.Close();


}
```

Comment: Hiya - gave this a go! Whilst it shows the error message if the UserName or Email match, it still inserts the record into the DB.

Comment: Hi @M.Ali - any feedback to my comment? Cheers Jack

Answer (score 0):

Instead of counting all users and adding 2 check just do one exists statement with 2 conditions.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select count(*) from [Customer] where CustomerUserName= @name AND CustomerEmail = @email)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [Customer] (CustomerFirstName,CustomerSurname,CustomerEmailAddress,CustomerAddress,CustomerAddressTown,CustomerAddressCity,CustomerAddressPostcode,CustomerContactNumber,CustomerUserName,CustomerPassword) VALUES (@FirstName, @Surname,@Email, @Address, @Town, @City, @Postcode,@ContactNumber,@Username,@Password)
END
```